# Find the point that is a given distance away from the other point on a curve using Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, open3d

I have a NumPy array that can be used to create a curve the array looks like this.

```
curve=np.asarray([0,0,0], [0.5,0,0], [0.8,0.2,0], [1,0.5,0], [1.2,0.7,0])
```

If I connect them up it will look like the following figure

[image]

The curve is in meters. Is there a Numpythonic way to find the points, on the curve, that is 1m, 2m, 3m, 4m etc, away from the origin (the blue point).

Thanks a lot for your great help and advice.

Sincerely

Wilson

Comment: I don't think there is a function for that. You would need to write your own.

Answer (score 0):

For each 3D coordinate in the array, compute the norm of the difference to the previous coordinate. This will give you an array of distances. In your example you get `[0, 0.5, 0.3606, 0.3606, 0.2828]`. The cumulative sum of this will give you the "distance walked" in the curve since the origin, which in this case is `[0, 0.5, 0.8606, 1.2211, 1.504]`.

You can use the code below

```py
a = np.array([[0,0,0], [0.5,0,0], [0.8,0.2,0], [1,0.5,0], [1.2,0.7,0]])
diffs = np.concatenate([[0], np.linalg.norm(np.diff(a, axis=0), axis=1)])
cumsum = np.cumsum(diffs)
```

Now, for each of your points of interest (1m, 2m, etc) you can find the indexes in the `cumsum` variable where the point of interest falls into. For instance, for 1m it would be indexes 2 and 3. Now, in index 2 you have walked a total of 0.8606, meaning that you still need to walk a distance of 0.1394 to reach a total of 1m. Just use the original coordinates in indexes 2 and 3 to compute the line equation then use that to find the appropriate coordinate. You can do that with

```py
v = a[3] - a[2]
v /= np.linalg.norm(v)
position_1m = a[2] + 0.1394 * v
```

With this, you get the coordinate for 1m as `[0.8773, 0.316, 0.]`.
The plot below shows the position corresponding to 1m as a red star.

[image: position of 1m in the curve]